# How to insert an ui grid with related records in an ui form

Tags: magento2, filter, ui-grid, insertlisting

I have inserted a grid in a form and I want to filter the listed records by the form id to show all related records.

[image]

Ho can I set the filter???
Please help me!!

---

Thats my dataprovider:

```
namespace Mcas\GhsCategory\Model\Ghscategory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * Loaded data cache
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * Data persistor
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param \Mcas\GhsCategory\Model\ResourceModel\Ghscategory\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        \Mcas\GhsCategory\Model\ResourceModel\Ghscategory\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        /** @var \Mcas\GhsCategory\Model\Ghscategory $ghscategory */
        foreach ($items as $ghscategory) {
            $this->loadedData[$ghscategory->getId()] = $ghscategory->getData();

        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('mcas_ghscategory_ghscategory');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $ghscategory = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $ghscategory->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$ghscategory->getId()] = $ghscategory->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('mcas_ghscategory_ghscategory');
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I understand clearly form id you are refering the the param id in URL whos value is 1 here ?

if yes then, if you are using dataprovider then you can the same param  value on request object and filter the collection. if using block then in block you can get the same and filter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I want to use the param 1 from Url, but I dont know how and where to use this value in my dataprovider. Can you explain, please.

Comment: can you please update your data provider Class code here, So I can modify for you reference.

Comment: asking for class which is handeling the grid ( the contact inforamtion part)

Comment: oh sorry, I have missunderstood